# Check if an email address exists or not in python

Tags: python

I would like to check if an email address exists or not in python 2.7.I used the SMTP server but it does not return any result.
Does anyone have an idea to check if an email address exists or not?

```
try:
    email_address = 'me@exemple.com'
    domain_name = email_address.split('@')[1]
    records = dns.resolver.query(domain_name, 'MX')
    mxRecord = records[0].exchange
    mxRecord = str(mxRecord)

    #Step 3: ping email server
    #check if the email address exists

    # Get local server hostname
    host = socket.gethostname()

    # SMTP lib setup (use debug level for full output)
    server = smtplib.SMTP()
    server.set_debuglevel(0)

    # SMTP Conversation
    server.connect(mxRecord)
    server.helo(host)
    server.mail('me@domain.com')
    code, message = server.rcpt(str(addressToVerify))
    server.quit()
    print(code)
    # Assume 250 as Success
    if code == 250:
        print('Y')
    else:
        print('N')
except Exception as error:
    print('Erreur:'+repr(error))
```

Comment: So the error is that the `try` block runs forverever before reaching a `print`? Otherwise you should at least see something.